# Javascript - how to position image in a table

Tags: javascript, image, html4

I am trying to position a 'random' image into a table column. Basically, I select the image based on the second that the the page is loaded - so 60 images available. The image selects and displays but locates itself at the page edge rather then the table edge.

I am going round in circles. Any hints on how to achieve this please? I am writing in HTML4 - I know very little about HTML5. The image width size is 480px, the column width in the table is 615px.

Here is my code.. with some debugs commented out.

Thanks
Martyn

## Introduction

```
<script>

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getSeconds();
var n = "hdrimages/"+n+".jpg"
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = n

//document.getElementById("hdrimage").innerHTML = img.src;
//document.getElementById("hdrimage").style.cssFloat = "right";
//hdrimage.style.float = “right”;

document.body.appendChild(img);

</script>
```

```
</td>
<td width="40%" align="left" valign="top"> 
<h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
<hr>
<h2>News</h2></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like following

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="img-cell"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and on JS part you can do

```
document.getElementById('img-cell').appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Perfect. That worked perfectly. A total newbie to JS so having to learn as I go along  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are appending the image to the body and not the table element

Answer (score 0):

Your current code only adds the image to the end of the body tag.
You need to add your image to the table data cell tag.
To do this, give your table data cell an id so you can find it then it,s easy to add:

```
<td id="myawesometabledatacell" width="40%" align="left" valign="top"> 
  <h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
  <hr>
  <h2>News</h2>
</td>

<script>
var d=new Date();
var n=d.getSeconds();
var n='hdrimages/'+n+'.jpg'
var img=document.createElement('img');
img.src=n
document.getElementById('myawesometabledatacell').appendChild(img);
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Two almost identical solutions.